# Check if UITextfield is active

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

The problem is that the "Eye Button" should only be displayed while the Textfield is selected. I have tried it with "isFirstResponder" but that doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas how to handle this? In the picture down below the textfield is not selected.

**Update**

The delegate function "password did change" works fine. The only thing I need is that the button should hide if the textfield is not selected anymore.  Adding the delegate functions "beging" or "endEditing" doesn't work. It just causes another fail where the text gets deleted if the user types something in, deselects the textfield and selects it back again.

```
@IBAction func passwordDidChange(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.passwordTextField.text == "" && self.passwordTextField.isFirstResponder != true{
        self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = true
    }else {
        self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = false
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you might want to change it and check for it in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method

Comment: How about assigning the button as `rightView` of the textField and setting its `rightViewMode` to `whileEditing`?

Comment: tried that before, but only one of them button gets displayed somehow. Either the "vergessen" button or the "eye button"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = true
        passwordTextField.delegate = self
    }

    // calls when textfield becomes 1st responder
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        switch textField {
        case passwordTextField:

            if passwordTextField.text != "" {
                self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = !self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden
            } else {
                self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = !self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden
            }

            break
        default:
            break
        }
        return true
    }

    //Calls when the text fields resigns first responder
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if textField == passwordTextField {
            if passwordTextField.text != "" {
                self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = !self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden
            } else {
                self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = !self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    // Check all the input user has with the keyboard.
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if let passwordTextField = passwordTextField {

            if passwordTextField.text?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = !self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden
            }

            if passwordTextField.text?.count == 0 {
                 self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = !self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        for textField in self.view.subviews where textField is UITextField {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but that crashed the App if I type something in and I get this error in my AppDelegate Class: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: ok i fixed the error. But your solutions doesn't to the job. The button is still there but now if I end editing and start editing again the text in the textfield gets deleted :D

Comment: you need to do something like `self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden = !self.eyeOpenButton.isHidden`

Comment: where? in each of the delegate functions?

Comment: doesn't do the job either.

Comment: I just updated my question. Hope you you can understand me :D

Comment: no. Right now there are two problem: 1. The Eye Button apears when the textfield is empty and the textfield is not selected.  2. The textinput gets deleted

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle this in `UITextfieldDelegate` method. Implement those methods and listen to changes and act accordingly.